# replace not wokring in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

https://www.kaggle.com/sudalairajkumar/indian-startup-funding
df=pd.read_csv("startup_funding.csv")

currently working on cleaning the dataset but , when i am trying to replace "\xc2\xa0" which is present in some rows , the below mentioned code is not working

```
def replacing(x):
    x=x.replace('\\xc2\\xa0','')
    return(x)

df['Investors Name']=df['Investors Name'].map(lambda x:replacing(x))
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Converting `x` to string before replacing values should do it:

```py
x=str(x).replace('\\xc2\\xa0','')
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Any error messages? Symbols are not replaced?

Comment: found the solution .
def replacing(x):
    x=str(x)
    x=x.replace('\\\\xc2\\\\xa0','')
    return(x)

df=df.applymap(lambda x:replacing(x))

Comment: @balaajevs That's exactly what I meant (just replace the first line inside replacing(x): with what I suggested)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Investors Name'] = df['Investors Name'].str.replace('\\xc2\\xa0','')
```

let me know if this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is something which worked for me.

```
def replacing(x):
    x=x.strip()
    x = x.replace(u'\\xc2', u' ')
    x = x.replace(u'\\xa0', u' ')
    x = x.replace(u'\ \ ',u'')
    return x
startup_df['Date dd/mm/yyyy']=startup_df['Date dd/mm/yyyy'].map(lambda x:replacing(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think a better option is to fix the encoding type of your data. But for a hacky solution, try

```
df['Investors Name'] = df['Investors Name'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.replace('\xc2\xa0',''))
```